# Difference Flex/Flash NetConnection and Consumer/Producer

Tags: flash, apache-flex, rtmp, producer-consumer, netconnection

What's the difference between a NetConnection and Consumer/Producer in Flex? It seems that they both use RTMP but Consumer/Producer uses Channels and NetConnection does not. Does the Consumer/Producer uses a NetConnection underneath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetConnection is a low-level Flash Player class that enables bidirectional communication between the Flash Player and a server. Both the RMI (remote objects) and Messaging (producer/consumer) implementations use NetConnection in their channels to do the actual communication to and from the server.

Comment: Thx, another question if I may. They both use NetConnection, but RMI uses http and messaging uses rtmp. Does this mean NetConnection can handle multiple protocols? Or am I missing something here?
+ is there documentation on this?

Comment: If NetConnection handles both of protocols, then IIS routes http requests to asp.net process. But what about rtmp? Do you know how IIS handles an rtmp request? (I know weborb starts a rtmpServer, but how does it intercept the rtmp requests?).